# How to test for equality for two ints in Java?

Tags: java, int, equality

I have only seen questions where `Integer` objects were involved in the discussion:

[Java: Integer equals vs. ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637936/java-integer-equals-vs)

[How do I compare two Integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873832/how-do-i-compare-two-integers)

and was wondering what the procedure should be for the primitive `int`.

```
int a = 250;
int b = 250;

System.out.println(a == b); // doesn't work for larger ints 127<
System.out.println(a.equals(b)); // doesn't work for primitive ints
```

What should one do in this case? Should one instead use the Object wrapper for `int`?

Comment: You compare `int` values using `==`.

Comment: your comment `// doesn't work for larger ints 127<` is incorrect, you're confusing that with behavior of the `Integer` Object.