# Different behavior of int and Integer

Tags: java

I noticed that the following code returns `false`

```
Integer a = 600;
Integer b = 600; 
System.err.println(a == b);
```

but this one

```
int a = 600;
int b = 600; 
System.err.println(a == b);
```

returns `true`

can anybody explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing to know is the values up to `128` are cached, and the JVM gives you the same objects,for that the reference comparison works. Above `128` it creates a new instance.

For more info go to [javadoc of Integer.valueOf(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29) (which is what happens behind the scene)

Comment: Then `Integer a = 20; Integer b = 20; System.err.println(a == b);` output: `true` why?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior **is correct**, in java `==` compares object references, it checks to see if the two operands point to the same object (not equivalent objects, the same object).

so your 1st example:

```
 Integer a = 600;
 Integer b = 600;
 System.err.println(a == b);
```

you are asking java to tell you if the have the same reference, which is false

in the example 2:

a and b are primitives, and you are asking java to tell you if the have the same value, which is True

[Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54742/jeff) had already an answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1874452/982161)

Comment: `Integer a = 100;
Integer b = 100; 
System.err.println(a == b);`
this one returns true